# Рекурсивное добавление\удалением элементов в дерево

Tags: c++, дерево, бинарное-дерево

```
class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        int info;

        Node() {
            left = right = nullptr;
        }

        ~Node() {}
    };

    Node *root;

    BinarySearchTree() {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    Node *GetNode() {
        return root;
    }
};
```

Собственно, само дерево выше. Не могу написать рекурсивную вставку и удаление. Итеративный вариант сделал. А вот с рекурсией проблемы.

```
void Insert(Node *node, int info) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        node = new Node();
        node->info = info;
    } else {
        if (info > root->info) {
            Insert(root->right, info);
        } else if (info < root->info) {
            Insert(root->right, info);
        };
    }
}
```

Пример использования дерева:

```
BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree->Insert(tree->GetNode(), 10);
```

Но root всегда указывает в NULL.

Comment: node * GetNode(){return root;} Не нужно давать переменным имена классов: void Insert(node * _node , int info)

Comment: Имена переменных исправил. Функцию тоже, однако все равно, после вставки, корень дерева указывает на NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема может быть в том, что у вас никогда не меняется переменная `root` класса `BinarySearchTree`. Исправить это можно, например, передавая в функцию `insert` не указатель на вершину дерева (`Node *node`), а ссылку на указатель (`Node *&node`).

```
class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    struct Node {
        Node *left = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
        int key;

        Node(int key) : key(key) {}
    };

    static void insert(Node *&node, int key) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            node = new Node(key);
        } else {
            if (key < node->key) {
                insert(node->left, key);
            } else if (key > node->key) {
                insert(node->right, key);
            }
//          если key == node->key, то такой ключ уже есть в дереве, поэтому мы ничего не делаем
        }
    }

    Node *root = nullptr;
public:
    void insert(int key) {
        insert(root, key);
    }
};

int main() {
    BinarySearchTree tree;
    tree.insert(10);
    return 0;
}
```